# JavaMail - Mail sent "ok"... but it doesn`t arrive

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, send

2 months ago, I configured JavaMail, to send emails for an app.
After several problemas I manage to solve (thanks some of them to stackOverflow), I send emails...
and It arrives to their recipients.

Now, trying again the process, It seems to send email (to the same recipients) ... 
but email don´t arrive (either inbox or spam).

Transport.send and the rest of the code, gives no exception.

What can be happening?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.

Comment: I can add the code, but code worked 2 months ago, I´ve not test again until yesterday... and It dont throw any error... but mails dont arrive to desntinatary

Answer (score 0):

If you get no errors from Transport.send, then your mail server has accepted the message for delivery.  If it's not delivering it, you need to check your mail server logs.

If it fails no matter what email address you send to, and no matter what the content of your message is, then something's wrong with your mail server.